# Refresh entire tkinter gui?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I've got a massive program that works flawlessly EXCEPT that I'm an idiot and all of the information is displayed via labels on the master/root window. When I remove one of the labels from the database it is pulling from it still shows the text as if the information still exists. If I close and reopen the entire program it loads the information correctly SO...

Rather than basically rewriting everyhing, within my update function I've placed:

`global master
master.destroy()
master = Tk()
master.title('Encounter Manager')`

And now the phantom information no longer shows, but it does exactly what you'd expect and closes/reopens the window. Is there a way to accomplish this without actually closing and reopening the window? It's annoying but still preferred to seeing the phantom information that I had since removed....

Comment: You never want to delete your root instance of Tk. Rather you can do this with a frame instead. Just make a frame fill the area needed for your labels and work everything in that frame. Then you can destroy and recreate that frame.

Comment: Perhaps you can update the "remove one of the labels from the database" code so that it looks up the appropriate label and removes it from the GUI. That way, you'll never have a phantom label, and you'll never need to do a window-level refresh.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add frame in the root window to hold the labels. So, root window -> frame -> labels. Then, you can destroy the frame and start over.

Another solution would be to iterate over the children of the root window and destroy them one by one:

```
for widget in root.winfo_children():
    widget.destroy()
```

Comment: I placed that within my update function and it works flawlessly. Thank you so much for the quick response, no more closing and reopening the entire window and no more phantom data :D